# setTimeout not working with an onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have the following:

```
onclick="setTimeout(overlayDisplayButton, 3000)"
```

It appears not to be working and I am starting to learn javascript/jquery, so most likely there is something wrong with the way I am doing.

I was trying originally to use callback so the overlay would disappear when the results were retrieved, but I do not fully understand how it works and so figured for the meantime, have a delay to show the results.

The following is script I am using:

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){

   $('#zip').on("input",function(){
       $('#city option[value=""]').prop('selected',true);

   })

    $('#city').on("change",function(){
       $('#zip').val("");
    })
})

function displayOverlay(text) {
    $("<table id='overlay'><tbody><tr><td>" + text + "</td></tr></tbody></table>").css({
        "position": "fixed",
        "top": "0px",
        "left": "0px",
        "width": "100%",
        "height": "100%",
        "background-color": "rgba(0,0,0,.6)",
        "z-index": "10000",
        "vertical-align": "middle",
        "text-align": "center",
        "color": "#fff",
        "font-size": "40px",
        "font-weight": "bold",
        "cursor": "wait",
        "overflow-y":"hidden"
    }).appendTo("body");
}

function removeOverlay() {
    $("#overlay").remove();
}

$(function overlayDisplayButton() {
    $(".btn").click(function () {
        if ($("#overlay").length > 0) {
            removeOverlay();
        } else {
            displayOverlay("Loading...");
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

And the following is the form that I am using that calls the setTimeout:

```
    <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-body">
<!---   <div id="loader" style="position: fixed; top:0; left:0; width:100%; height: 100%; background: url('loader.gif') center center #efefef"></div><!--Progress bar--->
        <form name="providerSearch" ng-submit="SearchProvider(searchParam);" novalidate="" role="form">
            <div class="form-group"><input class="form-control" id="physiciansfirstname" ng-model="searchParam.FirstName" placeholder="First name:" type="text" /></div>

            <div class="form-group"><input class="form-control" id="physicianslastname" ng-model="searchParam.LastName" placeholder="Last name:" type="text" /></div>

            <div class="form-group"><select class="form-control" id="providerSpecialty" ng-model="searchParam.Specialty"><option disabled="disabled" selected="selected" value="">Specialty</option>
            <option value=""></option><option>Family practice</option><option>General practice</option><option>Internal medicine</option><option>Pediatrics</option> </select></div>

            <div class="form-group">
             <SELECT name="proCity" class="form-control" id="city" placeholder="City" ng-model="searchParam.City">
                       <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected" value="">City</option> 
                          <option value=""></option>
                          <cfoutput query="cityFind">
                           <option value=#city#>#city#</option>
                        </cfoutput> 
                      </select>

            <!---<select class="form-control" id="city" ng-model="searchParam.City"><option disabled="disabled" selected="selected" value="">City</option><option ng-repeat="c in Cities">{{c.City}}</option> </select>---->
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-6 no-right-padding paddingLanguage">
                    <div class="form-group widthLanguage">


                    <select name="language" class="form-control" ng-model="searchParam.Language">
                        <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected" value="">Language</option>
                        <option value=""></option>
                     <cfoutput query="Languages">
                          <option value=#Language#>#Language#</option>
                        </cfoutput> 
                      </select>



                      <!---<select name="language" class="form-control widthLanguage" id="language" ng-model="searchParam.Language">
                        <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected" value="">Language</option>
                        <option ng-repeat="l in Languages">{{l.Lang}}</option>
                      </select>--->
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-xs-6 no-left-padding">
                    <div class="form-group"><select class="form-control" name="gender" ng-model="searchParam.Gender">
                    <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected" value="">Gender</option>
                    <option value=""></option>
                    <option>Male</option><option>Female</option> </select></div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <hr class="hrDoctor" />
            <div style="margin-top:-10px; margin-bottom:10px; text-align:center; font-size:8pt! important">* or Search by Zip code radius *</div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-7 no-right-padding">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="input-group"><select class="form-control" name="distance" ng-model="searchParam.distance"><option selected="selected">5</option><option selected="selected">10</option><option selected="selected">15</option><option selected="selected">20</option> </select>

                            <div class="input-group-addon">mi</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-xs-5 no-left-padding widthZip">
                    <div class="form-group"><input allow-pattern="[\d\-]" class="form-control" id="zip" maxlength="5" ng-model="searchParam.Zip" placeholder="Zip code" type="text" data-default=""/></div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group"><input class="btn btn-warning btn-block ignore" ng-click="gotoElement('SearchResultsAnchor');" onclick="setTimeout(overlayDisplayButton(), 3000)" type="submit" value="Search" /></div>
            <!---<div class="form-group buttonWidth resetButton"><input class="btn btn-primary btn-block" type="reset" value="Reset"  onClick="window.location.reload()"/></div>--->
        </form>
    <!---</div><!---Progress bar--->--->
    </div>
</div>
```

So I thought if I do the onclick and set it to equal to setTimeout(...), it would last for 3 seconds and then will let the user see the results.

However, that is not the case and not seeing what is the problem.

Comment: `overlayDisplayButton` adds a click handler to every `.btn` in the page. It doesn't run that click handler code. Every time you call `overlayDisplayButton` you're saying "okay, whenever I click a button I want this to happen" and they're just stacking up.

Comment: @MikeC Okay, so would I create blank id so it will be unique and the reason I say blank because I do not know what to add to this id

Comment: I have no idea how that relates to my comment.

Comment: @MikeC I do not understand then, sorry for the misunderstanding

Comment: @MikeC Okay rereading what you wrote, I understand. I have tried other ways where it is based on the body and it works fine however, if I click anywhere in the body, the overlay will appear which is not what I want

Comment: That also doesn't really relate to what I was saying. [Look at this example.](https://jsfiddle.net/ds4a5a8g/1/) Every time you click the "Add Another Handler" another handler is added to the "Click Me" button. If you click the "Click Me" button you'll see each new handler that was added. So your `overlayDisplayButton` is just adding a new handler every 3 seconds. You aren't running any code besides that.

Comment: @MikeC Okay I see what your trying to say. In my case, how would I use the setTimeout() function?

Answer (score 1):

Your current HTML isn't exactly what you copied:

```
<... onclick="setTimeout(overlayDisplayButton(), 3000)" ...>
```

The error is that you are *calling* `overlayDisplayButton`, instead of passing it as an argument.

In javascript functions are also **values**. The `setTimeout` function requires a function as first argument, so you should pass it like this:

```
<... onclick="setTimeout(overlayDisplayButton, 3000)" ...>
```

Besides that, it's correct what @Mike C points out: `overlayDisplayButton` is just adding an event handler to a button. Maybe what you want to do is this:

```
function overlayDisplayButton() {
    if ($("#overlay").length > 0) {
        removeOverlay();
    } else {
        displayOverlay("Loading...");
    }
}
```

Comment: @ mauroc8 I have done your suggested suggestion and I have done these changes before and it still does not work. I am not sure why it is not working. I thought if I did a callback and do something like: $('#PS').submit(function(event){
  //debugger;
 }); it would show me what is going wrong but it appears the ajax is being called. Not sure what is going on